# $scope filters element styles in angular

Tags: angularjs

This is a simple problem.

```
$scope.text = "<strong>this is text</strong>"
```

It outputs something like this

```
{{text}}
<strong>this is text</strong>
```

instead of

**this is text**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span ng-bind-html="text"></span>
```

check for ng-bind-html directive
dont forget to add `angular-sanitize.js` file

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml